# Access violation writing location 0x00BB9000

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on PNG formats. And, I'm trying to understand its characteristics:

> width, height, bytewidth, bytes per width, RGB pixel (red, green, blue)

Refering to [this](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) and [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html), width is the resolution width of the image in pixels, height is the resolution height of the image in pixels, bytes per width takes only 8 or 16 as value, RGB pixel's three items takes 0 to 255 as integer value.

But, I cannot understand what's a bytewidth?

Because when I try to convert one bmp image to a png one in C++ I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x01038F6C in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00BB9000.

I get this when I initialize the output png characteristics to:

> width = 1600,
>   height = 900,
>   bytewidth = 1, 
>   bytes per width = 1,
>   RGB pixel (red = 255, green = 255, blue = 255)

using this code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

#include <png.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct _RGBPixel {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
} RGBPixel;

/* Structure for containing decompressed bitmaps. */
typedef struct _RGBBitmap {
    RGBPixel *pixels;
    size_t width;
    size_t height;
    size_t bytewidth;
    uint8_t bytes_per_pixel;
} RGBBitmap;

/* Returns pixel of bitmap at given point. */
#define RGBPixelAtPoint(image, x, y) \
    *(((image)->pixels) + (((image)->bytewidth * (y)) \
                        + ((x) * (image)->bytes_per_pixel)))

/* Attempts to save PNG to file; returns 0 on success, non-zero on error. */
int save_png_to_file(RGBBitmap *bitmap, const char *path)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "wb");
    png_structp png_ptr = NULL;
    png_infop info_ptr = NULL;
    size_t x, y;
    png_uint_32 bytes_per_row;
    png_byte **row_pointers = NULL;

    if (fp == NULL) return -1;

    /* Initialize the write struct. */
    png_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (png_ptr == NULL) {
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Initialize the info struct. */
    info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
    if (info_ptr == NULL) {
        png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ptr, NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set up error handling. */
    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))) {
        png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set image attributes. */
    png_set_IHDR(png_ptr,
                 info_ptr,
                 bitmap->width,
                 bitmap->height,
                 8,
                 PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB,
                 PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
                 PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT,
                 PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT);

    /* Initialize rows of PNG. */
    bytes_per_row = bitmap->width * bitmap->bytes_per_pixel;
    row_pointers = (png_byte **)png_malloc(png_ptr, bitmap->height * sizeof(png_byte *));
    for (y = 0; y < bitmap->height; ++y) {
        uint8_t *row = (uint8_t *)png_malloc(png_ptr, sizeof(uint8_t)* bitmap->bytes_per_pixel);
        row_pointers[y] = (png_byte *)row;
        for (x = 0; x < bitmap->width; ++x) {
            RGBPixel color = RGBPixelAtPoint(bitmap, x, y);
            *row++ = color.red;
            *row++ = color.green;  /************* MARKED LINE ***************/
            *row++ = color.blue;
        }
    }

    /* Actually write the image data. */
    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
    png_set_rows(png_ptr, info_ptr, row_pointers);
    png_write_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);

    /* Cleanup. */
    for (y = 0; y < bitmap->height; y++) {
        png_free(png_ptr, row_pointers[y]);
    }
    png_free(png_ptr, row_pointers);

    /* Finish writing. */
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    RGBBitmap rgbbitmap;
    rgbbitmap.height = 1600;
    rgbbitmap.width = 900;
    rgbbitmap.bytes_per_pixel = 1;
    rgbbitmap.bytewidth = 1;

    RGBPixel rgbpixel;
    rgbpixel.blue = 255;
    rgbpixel.green = 255;
    rgbpixel.red = 255;
    rgbbitmap.pixels = &rgbpixel;

    save_png_to_file(&rgbbitmap, "abc.bmp");

        return 0;
}
```

I'm actually getting that error on the marked line.

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Comment: Should you not put a boundary check before `row++`?

Comment: bytewidth may mean "width of a byte in pixels" and then should be 8.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, When I do so, I get the same posted error on `RGBPixel color = RGBPixelAtPoint(bitmap, x, y);` line.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, may this is comming from RGB colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting

```
rgbbitmap.bytes_per_pixel = 3;  // was 1 which is probably wrong
```

Surely

```
uint8_t *row = (uint8_t *)png_malloc(png_ptr, sizeof(uint8_t)* bitmap->bytes_per_pixel);
```

must be

```
uint8_t *row = (uint8_t *)png_malloc(png_ptr, sizeof(uint8_t)* bitmap->bytes_per_pixel*bitmap->width);
```

, i.e. each row must hold enough space for all bytes in that row ;-), which is 3 bytes per pixel times pixels in a row. You actually compute that value, bytes_per_row, but for some reason fail to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, if I've correctly understood I need to also change the value of bytes_per_pixel to 3 ?

Comment: The intialization would be (1600,900,3,1,255,255,255) ?

Comment: Or is it because I'm simply not converting the `abc.bmp` to a `abc.png` one and overwriting it? And that I need to read each bytes_per_row for and to wrote it into a new png file?

Comment: @user3472134: I didn't see the funny file name. Why do you not name it according to its contents, i.e. *.png? Although that shouldn't do any harm here afaics because you never read its contents but simply overwrite it, so the name and previous contents is irrelevant.

Comment: it's a simple bmp image that I'm testing on this code. But, I think that I need to (read the bmp file and write)*(in loop) into the a ".png" one.

Comment: Yeah, well, one thing after the other ;-). But make sure to use two distinct files for the two images, and, as always, pay attention to names.

Comment: By reading and trying. Can you now get your png image constructed?

Comment: Not yet, but last question. How png characteristics should be initialized?

Comment: I thought (1600,900,3,1,255,255,255) looked ok. But I have never used a png lib, so I'm not familiar with the details. Btw, I saw similar code to yours at https://github.com/crust/pngpp/blob/master/png.cpp, maybe it helps.

Comment: How have you found that :O

Answer (score 0):

This

```
uint8_t *row = (uint8_t *)png_malloc(png_ptr, sizeof(uint8_t)* bitmap->bytes_per_pixel);
```

looks suspicious - I don't know how png_malloc() works, but I guess you're allocating `sizeof(uint8_t) * BytesPerPixel` (which is probably `sizeof(uint8_t) * 4`) instead of `sizeof(uint8_t) * NumberOfPixels`  (which should be considerably larger).

Comment: may this issue is comming from RGB colors?

Answer (score 0):

I think your rgbbitmap.bytes_per_pixel = 1 is wrong.
If your work in RGB8 your bytes_per_pixel = 3, in RGBA8 is 4 and so on.

Comment: When I replace that bytes_per_pixel by 3 or by 4, I get the same posted error on `RGBPixel color = RGBPixelAtPoint(bitmap, x, y);` line.

Comment: Why don't you try to access the request pixel via array style: pixels[(line + column) * bytes_count] ?

Comment: may this issue is comming from RGB colors?